# How to return object methods parameters

Tags: javascript

Here is part of my code

Actual Code:

Top:

```
var NS = (function (global) 
    {
```

Middle:

```
var ViewH = 
{
    portfolio: function ( embeddedAml ) 
        {
        internals
        },
```

Bottom:

```
return {    
    ViewHPortfolio:    ViewH.portfolio,
};

})(window);
```

However, IE is reporting that var1 is undefined.  I define it in the function parameter list and use it in the function.  Not too sure what the interpreter is realy saying.

These functions worked until I moved them into a common object - Container

Also IE would not let me pass Container.func1 so I passed it to the HTML as ContainerFunc1.

Question is, how do I get the interpreter to recognize the variables var1, var2...etc.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're a victim of semicolon insertion.

Change this:

```
return
  {
  ContainerFunc1:   Container.func1
  ContainerFunc2:   Container.func2
  }
```

to this:

```
return {
  ContainerFunc1:   Container.func1
  ContainerFunc2:   Container.func2
  };
```

Also, I think this

```
Container 
  {
    func1 : function(var1){...do something with var1...}
    func2 : function(var1){}
  }
```

Should be this

```
var Container = {
    func1 : function(var1){...do something with var1...}
    func2 : function(var1){}
  };
```

Finally, be aware that when you do

```
return {
  ContainerFunc1:   Container.func1
  ContainerFunc2:   Container.func2
};
```

And you say

```
var resultObj = Top();
resultObj.ContainerFunc1(X);
```

even though this function—`ContainerFunc1`—points to `Container.func1` the `this` inside the call will **not** be `Container`; `this` will be resultObj.

Finally, by convention functions that start with a capital letter in JavaScript are intended to be used as a constructor.  To comport with this convention you should consider changing the name to `top` with a lowercase `t`.

Comment: @stack.user.0 - you cannot do that.  JS will put a semicolon after return.  You need to say return { with the opening brace on the same line as return

Comment: You did not fix the `var` in front of `Container`